# Oracle Alter Index With Nested Select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table with several constraints (primary key, foreign keys, etc.).  Oracle generates indexes automatically with code names (for instance SYS_CO12345).  I want to rename the index with proper names.

I know how to identify the index name, using a request such as

```
SELECT INDEX_OWNER || '.' || INDEX_NAME
FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS
WHERE INDEX_OWNER = <my owner>
  AND TABLE_OWNER = <my table>
  AND TABLE_NAME = <my table>
  AND COLUMN_NAME = <my column>;
```

I also know how to rename an index, using a request such as

```
ALTER INDEX <index owner>.<index name> 
RENAME TO <index owner>.<index new name>;
```

Now, I would like to combine the two requests into something like :

```
ALTER INDEX
(
  SELECT INDEX_OWNER || '.' || INDEX_NAME
  FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS
  WHERE INDEX_OWNER = <my owner>
    AND TABLE_OWNER = <my owner>
    AND TABLE_NAME = <my table>
    AND COLUMN_NAME = <my column>
)
RENAME TO <index owner>.<index new name>;
```

But I face the following error message :

```
00953. 00000 -  "missing or invalid index name"
*Cause:    An index name of the form [ <identifier> . ] <identifier> is
           expected but not present. If OIDINDEX clause, index name must be
           <identifier>
*Action:   Enter an appropriate index name.
```

Any idea on how I could write the proper combined request?

Thank you very much for your help!

EDIT, after a suggestion from Multisync :
I wrote the following procedure, that works.  I'm not sure it's optimal, but it gets the job done...

```
DECLARE
  index_owner_and_name  VARCHAR2(30);
  query2execute VARCHAR2(200);

  CURSOR myCursor IS SELECT INDEX_OWNER || '.' || INDEX_NAME 
                     FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS 
                     WHERE INDEX_OWNER = <my owner>
                       AND TABLE_OWNER = <my owner>
                       AND TABLE_NAME = <my table>
                       AND COLUMN_NAME = <my column>;

BEGIN
  OPEN myCursor ;
  FETCH myCursor INTO index_owner_and_name;
  CLOSE myCursor ;
  query2execute := 'ALTER INDEX ' || index_owner_and_name  || ' RENAME TO <new index name>';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query2execute ;

END;
```

Comment: If you want dynamic DDL take a look at EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Comment: Thank you!  With your suggestion, I managed to write the following procedure and get the result done.  I'm not sure it is optimal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER INDEX syntax does not allow to feed its input from SELECT as INSERT-SELECT does. You cannot have a subquery in ALTER INDEX. You have to prepare each statement individually and run it through dynamic DDL (as Multisync already answered). This is the only way.